# global variables in python

Tags: python, variables, function

```
class AlphaBetaAgent(MultiAgentSearchAgent):

  def action(self,gamestate):
    self.alpha= -9999
    self.beta = 9999

    def abc(gamestate, depth, alpha, beta):


    def bvc(gamestate, depth, alpha, beta):


   return abc(gamestate, 0, alpha, beta)
```

I am calling the getAction function which itself calling the abc funct and abc function calling the bvc funct. The functions abc and bvc are working in recursive way. I need to modify the values of alpha and beta as per the situation demands so I made them local. BUt it is not letting me to do that. Error occurs

Error occurs:- global name 'alpha' is not defined

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In Python, it's *kind of* important.

Comment: yeah makes it kinda hard to read ;)

Comment: I suggest rewriting your function so that it actually does something rather than uselessly assigning values to function arguments and trying to return the value of a function that has no return value.

Comment: Im using these variables but I have not put down the whole code here...

Comment: -1: "I am calling the getAction function".  Yet, there is not `getAction` method shown in the example code.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, global variables must be declared outside of the function. Then, any function can *read* that variable without any problems, but if a function wants to write to it it has to declare it global. Example:

```
def fun1():
     print a
def fun2():
     a = 3
def fun3():
     global a
     a = 3
a = 0
fun1() # <- Will work
fun2() # <- Will raise exception
fun3() # <- Will work
```

Comment: name 'beta' is a function parameter and declared global - a error occurs like this when I apply your method

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is. If you want to use local variables in a function and manipulate them without worrying about global variables, that works fine, normally. I'm not sure quite what you are doing by declaring a function inside of a function. Have you tried classes instead?

Comment: there is a class in which a function Getaction is defined and in getAction fnction, i made 2 more functions

Answer (score 2):

Use a class. Storing state & behaviour is what classes are for.

Comment: +1: And avoid global variables.  They are often a terrible design blunder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want functions like `abc` and `bvc` to use common variables, you generally want to define an object for them to be methods of, like so:

```
class ActionState(object):
   def abc(self, gamestate, depth):
       self.alpha = -9999
       self.beta = 9999
   def bvc(self, gamestate, depth):
       self.alpha = -9999
       self.beta = 99999

def action(self, gamestate):
   state = ActionState()
   state.abc(gamestate, 0)
```

Alternatively, if you really want to, you can enclose a mutable object like a dict around to hold your data:

```
def action(self, gamestate):
    actionstate = { 'alpha': 0, 'beta': 0 }

    def abc(gamestate, depth):
        actionstate['alpha'] = -9999
        actionstate['beta'] = 9999

    def bvc(gamestate, depth):
        actionstate['alpha'] = -9999
        actionstate['beta'] = 9999

    abc(gamestate, 0)
```

Note that the `actionstate` parameter isn't passed here -- it's inherited from the enclosing scope.  You can pass it explicity instead if you want, in which case `abc` and `bvc` no longer need to be defined inside of `action`.  The reason this works and your example doesn't is that Python binds any primitive identifier lexically to the most-local function where it is assigned.  So when you assign to `alpha` in `abc`, Python defines an `alpha` as local to `abc`, not `action`.  I believe the only way to get a closure in Python is not to assign to the enclosed variable within the inner function.

Comment: the abc and bvc functions are defined in the function getAction. So where do I exactly define my alpha and beta....I cant use self.alpha??

Comment: `alpha` and `beta` must be defined as components of a dictionary or object which is created above the definitions of `abc` and `bvc`.  That way you can assign to them without creating a second version in a more-local scope.  See added explanation at end of answer.

Comment: Also, why can't you use `self.alpha`?

Comment: When I use self.alpha and self.beta , error occurs. Im not writing the function def abc(self,gamestate,alpha, beta)- it is def abc(gamestate, depth,alpha , beta)

Comment: See my first example code -- if you use an object, you do have to change the method signature of `abc` and `bvc`.  You add `self` at the beginning and also drop the alpha and beta parameters, because those are kept inside of `self`.  Then you call `abc` and `bvc` as methods instead of functions, so they get their implicit self parameters, as also demonstrated in my example.  Note that just because a function has a particular signature in some pseudocode you found somewhere, it doesn't necessarily have to look like that when you write it, as long as the same job gets done!

Comment: In your example, def getaction is single function. BUt in my case, It has 2 functions def abc and def bvc. ABC and BVC are part of function getAction. I tried to do what you said, but a error occurs like" AlphaBetaAgent instance has no attribute 'abc'

Comment: I moved abc and bvc out of `getAction` deliberately.  For it to work they have to be part of the class.  Why do they have to be part of `getAction` if all the shared state they need is moved into instance variables of the class?

Answer (score 0):

To use a global variable you have to do something like:

global alpha 
alpha = -9999

Comment: No when I put the values of alpha & beta inside the function, then a error occurs like global name"alpha " is not defined. When i declared the alpha and beta outside def abc, then it works fine. I want to use alpha nd beta s local variables.